# How to access Java property in terminal

Tags: java, bash, terminal

I know I can get all the Java System properties from the terminal using

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

How do I access just one specific java system property? 
For example, like "user.name"?

I want to do this in the terminal, not with Java.

Comment: In java way, the answer is NO. But if you want to know the user, you can user unix command or windows command to know the user name of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution as a one liner script. Just change the `val` variable to the key you want to print:

```
val='java.library.path'; java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | sed -re 's/^ +[^=]+ =/_&/' | gawk -v key=$val 'BEGIN{ RS="_"; IFS=" = "} { if($1 ~ key){ print $0 }}'
```

**Details**
Some property values like `java.library.path` contain new lines so we need to mark records before filtering and printing them.
`sed` allows us to do that, then `awk` can be used to filter and print.

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 |\
sed -re 's/^ +[^=]+ =/_&/' |\
gawk -v key=java.library.path 'BEGIN{ RS="_"; IFS=" = "} { if($1 ~ key){ print $0 }}'
```

Result:

```
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
```

Pipeline parts explained:

`2>&1`: properties are printed to stderr so we need to redirect them to stdin.

`sed -re 's/^ +[^=]+ =/_&/'` : add an underscore in front of interesting lines, those starting with 4 spaces and containing `=`.

`gawk -v key=java.library.path`: set `key`awk variable to the selected property key.

`'BEGIN{ RS="_"; IFS=" = "}`: set record separator to '_' and input field separator IFS to `=`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the current logged in user in bash just use `whoami` command. If you want to get the java property from terminal you can use the following command

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep user.name
```

which will print

```
$java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep user.name
    user.name = user
```

If you just need the user name only

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep user.name | cut -c 16-100
```

which will print

```
$java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep user.name | cut -c 16-100
user
```

Comment: While this *does* allow you to get a value that's generally equal to `user.name`, this doesn't actually generalize to answer the question being asked, if another property were to be substituted.

Comment: Is there are more standardized way of doing it? I need several other variables as well.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov Yes, I was testing grep it was not working directly. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

What you can do is create a java file to get the information and run with java, [here the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Since you already said that you don't want this, you can grep (filter) the output of

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep java.home
java.home = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/jre
```

If you want to know the system properties of a running jvm, use the [jcmd tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jcmd.html)

```
jcmd PID VM.system_properties
```